# LSN external representation

Tags: postgresql

According to postgres documentation, LSN is a 64-bit integer, representing a byte position in the write-ahead log stream. It is printed as two hexadecimal numbers of up to 8 digits each, separated by a slash; for example, 16/B374D848.
Does anyone know what is the meaning of these 2 hexadecimal numbers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Left pad the part right of the slash with zeros, then remove the slash, and you have the offset in bytes described by the documentation.

Comment: sorry but I don't understand, since the right part of the / already has 8 digits 16/B374D848 where zeros must be placed. Thanks four your help

Comment: Then the left padding will do nothing in this case :^) An LSN could also look like `16/374D848`, which then would correspond to 160374D848.

Comment: Then the python code to convert `restart_lsn = "16/374D848"` into `int` would be 
`int("".join(map(lambda x: x.zfill(8), restart_lsn.split('/'))), base=16)`, which equals 94547269704. Thanks Laurenz! 

Answer (score 7):

`pg_lsn` type supports `-` operation and returns byte offset, so here is the simplest way to convert from pg_lsn to bigint:

```
SELECT pg_current_wal_lsn() - '0/0'
```

Answer (score 3):

Quoting the documentation that you can find [here](https://pgpedia.info/x/xlogrecptr.html) :

> In PostgreSQL 9.2 and earlier, XLogRecPtr was a struct consisting of two 32 bit integers:

```
typedef struct XLogRecPtr
{
     uint32     xlogid;         /* log file #, 0 based */
     uint32     xrecoff;        /* byte offset of location in log file */
} XLogRecPtr;
```

and

> As of PostgreSQL 9.3, XLogRecPtr is an unsigned 64 bit integer, defined in include/access/xlogdefs.h:

```
typedef uint64 XLogRecPtr;
```

I don't know if there is a daily usage in the work of the database administrator : if I understand correctly you are looking for a mean to convert the external representation (pg_lsn) to the internal representation (64-bit integer) ? if this is it, and using your example : 16/B374D848
you are looking for this kind of answer :

```
# select x as bit_stream, bit_length(x), x::int8 as int8 from (select ('x' || lpad(split_part('16/B374D848', '/', 1), 8, '0') || lpad(split_part('16/B374D848', '/', 2), 8, '0'))::bit(64)) as t(x);
```

bit_stream|bit_length|int8
0000000000000000000000000001011000000000000000000000000000000000|64|94489280512
(1 row)

Looking into the [code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/utils/adt/pg_lsn.c) (see the pg_lsn_in_internal function) you have another mean using this kind of SQL :

```
# select ('x' || lpad(split_part('16/B374D848', '/', 1), 8, '0'))::bit(32)::bigint << 32 | ('x' || lpad(split_part('16/B374D848', '/', 2), 8, '0'))::bit(32)::bigint;
```

?column?
97500059720
(1 row)

As you can see in the code there is still 2 parts, the first part is the id and the second part is the offset into the logical WAL file name. This is what I understand of the code. The old version of the type is still used using bit function.